# How to add a slug to username for Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, slug

Usually, I create slugs like this:

```
params[:user][:name_slug] = params[:user][:name].parameterize
```

But this quite problem with Devise - how can I add it?
I've created a controller where I specified attributes that are needed for creating a user, but how to add the slug there?

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private
    def sign_up_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :name_slug, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

  protected
    def update_resource(resource, params)
      resource.update_without_password(params)
    end
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that in your `User` model:

```
before_validation :generate_slug

# ...

private
def generate_slug
  self.name_slug = name.to_s.parameterize
end
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about this option! (btw, it should be `before_validation :generate_slug`)